# issue instantiating object of Java generic class

Tags: java, generics

I've been going around in circles trying to understand Java generics. I'm having trouble instantiating an object of a generic class. Any insight to where I'm going wrong?

In one document, the generic class:

```
public class SearchSortAlgorithms<T> implements SearchSortADT<T>
{
  …
    public void quickSort(T[] list, int length)
    {
        recQuickSort(list, 0, length - 1);
    }
  …
}
```

In another:

```
public class TestQuickSort
{  

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {  

        // define an Integer array of 50000 elements
        Integer[] anArray = new Integer[5000];

        // load the array with random numbers using
        // a for loop and Math.random() method - (int)(Math.random()*50000)
        for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
        {
            anArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * i);
        }


        // print the first 50 array elemnts with a for loop
        // using System.out.print
        for (int j = 0; j <= 50; j++) {
             System.out.print(anArray[j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();

        // define an object of SearchSortAlgorithm with Integer data type
        // use this object to call the quickSort method with parameters: your array name and size-5000

        SearchSortAlgorithms<Integer> anotherArray = new SearchSortAlgorithms<Integer>(); //This is where I get my error message
        anotherArray.quickSort(anArray, 5000);


        // print out the first 50 array elements with a for loop
        // they have to be sorted now
        for (int k = 0; k <= 50; k++) {
             System.out.print(anotherArray[k] + " ");
        } 
   }

}
```

Error message:

```
java:39: array required, but SearchSortAlgorithms<java.lang.Integer> found
```

Comment: Where is `aSortedArray` declared? What is it declared as?

Comment: @Sotirios that's a typo--i changed it to anotherArray

Comment: @tambykojak line 39: System.out.print(anotherArray[k] + " ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax

```
anotherArray[k]
         // ^ ^
```

only works with array types. `anoterArray` is not declared as an array.

Did you mean to use `anArray`?

Comment: that must be my problem. I'm a beginner to java--can you give me a hint as to how I would do so?

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean. when using the object to call the method on anArray, anArray is sorted directly. I'm not populating the object anotherArray with sorted items from anArray?

Comment: I think what he meant was did you mean to write              `System.out.print(anArray[k] + " ");` in the last line

Comment: @user25976 You haven't shown all your code, but you seem to be sorting the passed array in place. The important thing to note here is that `anotherArray` is not an array. The `[]` don't make sense with it.